# Adding Data to an existing SeriesCollection in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a chart from data inside an Excel sheet. Everything works. But now I want to remove values that are below a limit and display them as "Others". Removing them works but I don't know how to add an additonal "others" value.

This is part of the code:

```
Co.chart.SetSourceData Source:=DataSource
Co.chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Best selling games"
Co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels ShowPercentage:=True, ShowValue:=False

For Each d In Co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels
  v = CLng(Split(d.Caption, "%")(0))
  If v < 10 Then
    Rest = Rest + v
    d.Delete
  End If
Next
If Rest > 0 Then
    Co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.AddData("Others",Rest); ' HERE    
End If
```

In the second last line is some pseudocode about what I want to achieve.

Comment: A comment for downvote would be nice. Imho: It is clear what I am asking and a clear programming-related question

Comment: Would it be just as easy to just change the range of values in the series all togehter (e.g., `Co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = (your new range here)`?

Comment: No. The "others" value does not exist inside the sheet but is calculated inside the function

Comment: Maybe you could store `Others` into an array and try `Co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Others`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a "dirty" solution for this. Instead of deleting the first item I RENAME it to "Others" instead of deleting it and adding the "Others" afterwards:

```
For Each d In Co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels
                Counter = Counter + 1
                v = CLng(Split(d.Caption, "%")(0))
                If v <= 10 Then
                    If RestPos < 0 Then
                        RestPos = Counter
                    Else
                        d.Delete
                    End If
                    Rest = Rest + v

                End If
            Next
            If Rest > 0 Then
                Co.chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(RestPos).Caption = Rest & " %"
```

End If